# Android rotate Bitmap and draw Canvas

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I am trying to rotate a Bitmap using matrix . Then I am trying to draw it on Canvas . But it just DISAPPEARS !

Here is my code below :

```
    public class MultitouchView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private static final String TAG = "MultitouchView";
private Drawable image;
private Drawable userImage;

Bitmap userOriginal;
Bitmap userResult;

private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;

private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private int direction = 0;

Context context;

public MultitouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.plain_black_wallpaper);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            image.getIntrinsicHeight());

    userOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.navigation);

    userImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation);
    userImage.setBounds(500, 500, 550, 550);

    setFocusable(true);

    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
            new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Set the image bounderies
    canvas.save();
    //scale canvas
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    image.draw(canvas);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    //rotate user drawable

    userImage.draw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();
}

 public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
        rotateBitmap();
        invalidate();
      }

private void rotateBitmap() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(this.direction);
    userResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(userOriginal,0,0, userOriginal.getWidth(), userOriginal.getHeight(), matrix,true);
    userImage=new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),userResult);

}
```

}

I have removed the functions for scale canvas and event listener etc . to make the code small and readable here.

I call the setDirection method  periodically but then after it is called the "userImage" drawable just disappears . Can anyone please suggest as to what is going wrong here ..

Thanks

Comment: so, what is your requirement exactly? do you want to rotate userImage and draw it on Canvas?

Comment: yep thats true .. I want to rotate image and draw the image "drawable" and not the BitMapdrawable... as I am handling some events on that drawable later which is necessary ...

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was wrong .. The rotate Bitmap was functioning fine but since I dont set the bounds on the drawable the "userImage" drawable was getting drawn at location 0,0 with a height and width of 0,0 hence it was DISAPPEARING . I fixed by changing hte rotate bitmap function as shown below :

```
private void rotateBitmap() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(this.direction);
    userResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(userOriginal,0,0, userOriginal.getWidth(), userOriginal.getHeight(), matrix,true);
    userImage=new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),userResult);
    userImage.setBounds(500, 500, 550, 550);

}
```

the userImage.Setbounds needed to be implemented...